# Django FileField on Model, Delete File When Deleting Model and Confirmation

Tags: python, django

I have an upload dashboard with an upload form and a table where it shows files.  In the final column are actions such as delete.  But when I press delete it deletes the model in the database, but the file is still in the folder.  I want the file deleted from this folder too, and it would be even nicer if I could move the deleted file to another directory something like a recycle bin so admins can see files even when they are deleted by the user who uploaded them.  (The userbase is under 10 so it can be simple)

Other than that, I was wonderng if there is a way to include in the pre_delete a confirmation alert box of some sort, so that when they press delete it asks in a dialogue for confirmation.

Here is the code I have so far:

My Views one for the dashboard and one for the for deletion:

```
@login_required(login_url='/dashboard-login/')
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client
   
    files = ClientUpload.objects.filter(client=current_client)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            dz_files = request.FILES.getlist('file_upload')
            for f in dz_files:
                new_file = ClientUpload(client=current_client, file_upload=f)
                new_file.save() 
                logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                logger.info("File uploaded from " + current_client.company)
        else:
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.warning("Upload Failed")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
   
    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def dashboard_delete(request, upload_id):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client
    form = UploadFileForm()

    p = ClientUpload.objects.get(pk=upload_id)
    p.delete()

    files = ClientUpload.objects.filter(client=current_client)
    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}

    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My Model and signal:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUpload(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")

@receiver(post_delete, sender=ClientUpload)
def clientupload_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.file:
        # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
        instance.file.delete(False)
    else:
        # log failure
```

My  template for the file list:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load sasite_filters %}

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Filename{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Size (Bytes){% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Upload Time{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Actions{% endblocktrans %}</th>
</tr>
{% for file in files %}
    {% with uploaded_file=file.file_upload %}  
 <tr>
    <th><a href='{{ uploaded_file.url }}'>{{ uploaded_file.name|pathend}}</a></th>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.size }}</th>
    <th>{{ file.created_at }}</th>
    <th><a href="{% url 'dashboard-delete' file.id %}">Delete</a></th>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>   
</table>
```

My urls for the dashboard's delete:

```
url(r'^dashboard/delete/(?P<upload_id>\d+)$', views.dashboard_delete, name='dashboard-delete'),
```

Is this all I need to do to ensure the file is deleted?  Did I use the signal correctly?  Am I missing a step?  I just want to make sure, because I'm trying to add to the signal that I want the file to be copied to a "Recycle Bin" directory before I erase it, it doesn't need a model at this point, can just be a file in the directory.  But in any case I want it deleted from it's upload_to directory and moved to another directory, before I finish up deleting the  model.

Is pre or post delete the correct one to be using here?  And for the confirmation box for deletion?  Should I use pre_delete or should I be using JavaScript for a confirmation dialogue?  I am unsure.  Any examples/suggestions are of big help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first approach should work with this change: `instance.file_upload.delete(False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo this works fine:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=ClientUpload)
def clientupload_postdelete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.file_upload:
        filename = os.path.basename(instance.file_upload.path)
        client = instance.client.company

        folder_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploads/Recycle/', client + '/')
        if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.makedirs(folder_path)

        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder_path, filename)):
            filename = append_id(filename)

        shutil.move(instance.file_upload.path, os.path.join(folder_path, filename))

        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("File %s moved to %s" % (filename, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle/' + client + '/'))
        # Pass False so FileField doesn't save the model.
        instance.file_upload.delete(False)
    else:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning("Failed to find file for copying to %s." % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle/'))
```